# Getting value of enum on string conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.4

I have the following enum defined:

```
from enum import Enum
class D(Enum):
    x = 1
    y = 2

print(D.x)
```

now the printed value is

```
D.x
```

instead, I wanted the enum's value to be print

```
1
```

What can be done to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I should clarify the access parameters, I know the D.x.value thing, what I want is D.x string conversion to return the value, sorry if question doesn't make the condition clear.

Answer (score 436, accepted):

You are printing the enum *object*. Use the `.value` attribute if you wanted just to print that:

```
print(D.x.value)
```

See the [*Programmatic access to enumeration members and their attributes* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes):

> If you have an enum member and need its name or value:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> member = Color.red
> >>> member.name
> 'red'
> >>> member.value
> 1
> ```

You could add a `__str__` method to your enum, if all you wanted was to provide a custom string representation:

```
class D(Enum):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    x = 1
    y = 2
```

Demo:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class D(Enum):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(self.value)
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
... 
>>> D.x
<D.x: 1>
>>> print(D.x)
1
```

Comment: When I compare it with a integer value, it returns as object. Ex: `if  D.x == 10: ...`. What approach should I take for integers?

Comment: @alper: exactly the same way; `D.x` is the enum object, `D.x.value` is an integer value. If you must have the enum values act like integers, use the [`IntEnum` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum), where each element is a subclass of `int` and so `IntEnumD.x == 10` would work.

Comment: I have added  `def __eq__(self, other):
        return int(self.value) == other` and `def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)` but still I think I have to use `.value` on cases when I don't use comparing

Comment: @alper: that `__eq__` implementation doesn't work when `other` is another enum value; `D.x == D.y`, where `D.x.value == D.y.value` would be true, would fail for example. It sounds like you want to use `IntEnum` instead of `Enum` there.

Comment: .value is really annoying since it pollutes your code with a bunch of .value. A solution without .value would be great. I am still using Enum by principle  (more precisely,  class MyEnumClass(str, Enum): ...) but I must admit I prefer the use of a constants class since I can avoid the .value pollution.

Comment: @Greg7000: what are you using `.value` *for*? If you have a `...(str, Enum)` enum, your members are already strings so anything that accepts a string can use that directly for most contexts. E.g. `f"The member is: {MyEnumClass.membername}"`, etc. You can always add your own `__str__` method for those contexts that call `.__str__()` (like print()).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, you are right I was wrong. At some point in time I faced a context where not using .value caused me an issue but this was either invalid or a twisted case. Thx for the remark.

Answer (score 30):

I implemented access using the following

```
class D(Enum):
    x = 1
    y = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.value
```

now I can just do

`print(D.x)` to get `1` as result.

You can also use `self.name` in case you wanted to print `x` instead of `1`.

Comment: Why the string formatting and `self._value_`? `return str(self.value)` is more straightforward.

Comment: I just looked at the source and this was how it is implemented, however you are right and `self.value` is cleaner.

Comment: The single-underscore attributes are internal to the generated enum class; better stick to the documented attribute (which happens to be a special descriptor so that you can still use `value` as a name on your enum type).

Answer (score 17):

If you are going to print value using f-string then you can inherit your enum from both `Enum` and `str`. This way you can have both value and name of the object. For instance:

```
from enum import Enum


class D(str, Enum):
    x = 1
    y = 2

print(D.x)
print(f"{D.x}")
```

Outputs:

```
D.x
1
```

Inheriting just from `Enum` will always give a full qualified name.

```
class D(Enum):
    x = 1
    y = 2

print(D.x)
print(f"{D.x}")
```

Output

```
D.x
D.x
```

This is opposite to if you not inherit from anything where you will get value instead of name:

```
class D:
    x = 1
    y = 2


print(D.x)
print(f"{D.x}")
```

Output

```
1
1
```

That is why inheriting from both `str` and `Enum` you are getting both full qualified name and the value.

Comment: is this definition of yours equivalent to :
`class D(Enum, str):
    x = 1
    y = 2
`

Comment: I like this answer the most. But I fail to understand why `print(D.x)` prints `D.x` whereas `print(f"{D.x}")` prints the actual value `1`. @Vlad may I kindly ask you to elaborate a bit more on your answer. Additionally, why does `str(D.x)` also returns `D.x`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gmagno, I updated the answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to compare your enum members to `Int` values, a better way to do it would be to extend `IntEnum`:

```py
from enum import IntEnum


class D(IntEnum):
    x = 1
    y = 2


print(D.x)
```

In this way you can compare values of your enum against integers without explicitly calling `.value`:

```py
>>> D.x == 1
True
```

For more information you can check this part of the Python docs: [Enum comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons)

Comment: I guess this answer should be the correct solution since the answer of @Martijn Pieters returns the “position value” which happens to be identical with the assign value. If x would be assigned to 5, `D.x` would return 1 anyways and not 5.

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward dunder method to use is __*repr*__ instead of __*str*__ since it will also allow you to print it in that way also in lists.

```
class D(Enum):
  x = 1
  y = 2

  def __repr__(self):
      return self.value

print([D.x,D.y])
>>> [1, 2]
```

EDIT:

Since it will still print D.x if you use print(D.x), I think a better way to achive this is by adding the __*str*__ method also.

```
class D(Enum):
  x = 1
  y = 2

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.value)

  def __repr__(self):
      return str(self)
```

Comment: It will still print `D.x` if you use `print(D.x)`