# Referring Enum members to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined the following Enum in Python:

```
class Unit(Enum):
    GRAM = ("g")
    KILOGRAM = ("kg", GRAM, 1000.0)

    def __init__(self, symbol, base_unit = None, multiplier = 1.0):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.multiplier = multiplier
        self.base_unit = self if base_unit is None else base_unit
```

I would expect that

```
print(Unit.GRAM.base_unit)
print(Unit.KILOGRAM.base_unit)
```

will return

```
Unit.GRAM
Unit.GRAM
```

However, what I get is quite confusing

```
Unit.GRAM
g
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python enum - getting value of enum on string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487405/python-enum-getting-value-of-enum-on-string-conversion)... also, take a look at how to represent the `str` unit in the other (unaccepted) answer

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  This question is asking how members can refer to each other before the class has been fully constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Python defines a class involves creating a new scope, processing a bunch of statements (variable assignments, function definitions, etc.), and *then* actually creating a class object based on the local variables which exist after all those statements have run. Nothing gets converted into `Enum` instances until that last step.

You could understand it somewhat like this:

```
def make_class_Unit():
  GRAM = ("g")
  KILOGRAM = ("kg", GRAM, 1000.0)

  def __init__(self, symbol, base_unit = None, multiplier = 1.0):
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.multiplier = multiplier
    self.base_unit = self if base_unit is None else base_unit
  return make_class(name='Unit', base=Enum, contents=locals())

Unit = make_class_Unit()
```

Looking at it this way, hopefully you can tell that at the time when `KILOGRAM` is defined, `GRAM` is really just a string. It doesn't become a `Unit` instance until the last stage, where I call the (imaginary) `make_class()` function.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Even though the `make_class` function I used above doesn't actually exist under that name, it's not too different from what Python really does, which is calling the constructor of `type` or a metaclass (which in this case is the metaclass for `Enum`s).

Answer (score 1):

DavidZ explained the problem well.

The last bit that you need to solve this problem is this:  when the `__init__` of each member is being run, the `Enum` has been created -- so you can call it:

```
self.base_unit = self if base_unit is None else self.__class__(base_unit)
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought that, perhaps, `Unit.KILOGRAM.base_unit` and `Unit.GRAM` will refer to different objects, but `id(Unit.GRAM)`, `id(Unit.KILOGRAM.base_unit)`, `id(Unit.GRAM.base_unit)` all return same id. So there are no redundant instances.