# How to convert Enum names to strings?

Tags: python

Not a duplicate of: [enum - getting value of enum on string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487405/enum-getting-value-of-enum-on-string-conversion).

The question here is about how to the get `Enum` name (left part) converted to a string, not the value (right part).

With the following `Enum`:

```
class test(Enum):
    aa = 1
    bb = 2
```

I can do this:

```
v = test.aa
print(v)
```

and I get:

`test.aa`

but how do I convert `v` to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the `name` attribute on the object:

```
from enum import Enum

class test(Enum):
    aa = 1
    bb = 2

v = test.aa
print(v.name)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> aa
> ```

Comment: the str() way works too; coming from a c# background, I have a hard time to remember that everything in python is abbreviated! I think string, not str, length, not len, etc :)

Comment: but this is exactly what I need: a string with test.aa, not '1'

Comment: @Thomas Ahh, ok, then calling `var = str(v)` is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value or the enum itself

`str(test.aa.value) == 1` .

`str(test.aa) == 'test.aa'` .

`print(test.aa)` will also cast it to a string