# Python Enum Class with String Constants

Tags: python

Is it possible to implement enumerations in Python with string constants (or any other arbitrary data type). I would like to something as

```
class Color(Enum):
    black = "black as night"
    white = "white as snow"
    green = "green as gras"
```

The reason, not hard to guess, is to use the constants of the enumeration directly as strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enum - getting value of enum on string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487405/enum-getting-value-of-enum-on-string-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use strings in enumerations in Python, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api).
Check also the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) on enumerations.

Enum were introduced in Python version 3.4.

WARNING : These links concern the Python version 3.8.3

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26069982)

Comment: @GinoMempin: Indeed the link may change, yet I really do not know what else can I add to the description of my answer. The answer is all there. I shall try to add something more ...

Comment: My post answers precisely the question. If someone finds my answer is not good : please edit the answer with the appropriate changes. Otherwise, you may write a better answer yourself.